# Route '0' requires Hosts or Path specified. Set the Path to '/{**catchall}' to match all requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, gateway, ms-yarp

I am trying to use Yarp in my gateway app for routing my applications. However as soon as it's started, I get "Route '0' requires Hosts or Path specified. Set the Path to '/{**catchall}' to match all requests."

Here is my AppSettings file:

```
 "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": [
      {
        "SampleService": {
          "ClusterId": "SampleService-cluster1",
          "Match": {
            "Host": "localhost",
            "Path": "sample/{**catchall}"
          }
        },
        "NotificationService": {
          "ClusterId": "NotificationService-cluster",
          "Match": {
            "Host": "localhost",
            "Path": "api/NotificationService/{**catchall}"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Clusters": {
      "SampleService-cluster1": {
        "Destinations": { "SampleService-cluster1/destination1": { "Address": "http://127.0.0.1:6500" } }
      },
      "NotificationService-cluster": {
        "Destinations": { "NotificationService-cluster/destination1": { "Address": "http://*:6020" } }
      }
    }
  }
```

ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("any", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddTelemetryConsumer<ForwarderTelemetry>();

            services.AddReverseProxy()
                .LoadFromConfig(Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));
        }
```

And I get this:
[System.InvalidOperationException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHbcz.png)

So any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a breaking changes in [v1.0.0-preview11](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/releases/tag/v1.0.0-preview11) for the way `Routes` are configured. You need to update your setting.

```
"ReverseProxy": {
  "Routes": {
    "SampleService": {
      "ClusterId": "SampleService-cluster1",
      "Match": {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Path": "sample/{**catchall}"
      }
    },
    "NotificationService": {
      "ClusterId": "NotificationService-cluster",
      "Match": {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Path": "api/NotificationService/{**catchall}"
      }
    }
  },
  "Clusters": {
    "SampleService-cluster1": {
      "Destinations": { "SampleService-cluster1/destination1": { "Address": "http://127.0.0.1:6500" } }
    },
    "NotificationService-cluster": {
      "Destinations": { "NotificationService-cluster/destination1": { "Address": "http://*:6020" } }
    }
  }
}
```